# Predict with mapply

Tags: r, list, mapply

I'm relatively new to `r`. I was wondering if it was possible to translate

```
preds <- data.frame(predict(fit, testdf[,predictorNames], se.fit = TRUE)[[1]])
```

where `fit` is a linear regression model and `testdf` is a dataframe, to something like:

```
predfit  <- mapply('predict', lmfit, testlist[,predictorNames])
```

where `lmfit` is the list of linear regression models, length 3, and `testlist` a list of length 1.

I hope to use this to write a bagging function with lists, simliar to: http://amunategui.github.io/bagging-in-R/

Here the `dput(head(test_df))`:

```
test_df <- structure(list(crim = c(0.02177, 0.0351, 0.02009, 0.13642, 0.22969, 0.25199), zn = c(82.5, 95, 95, 0, 0, 0), indus = c(2.03, 2.68, 2.68, 10.59, 10.59, 10.59), chas = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), nox = c(0.415, 0.4161, 0.4161, 0.489, 0.489, 0.489), rm = c(7.61, 7.853, 8.034, 5.891, 6.326, 5.783), age = c(15.7, 33.2, 31.9, 22.3, 52.5, 72.7 ), dis = c(6.27, 5.118, 5.118, 3.9454, 4.3549, 4.3549), rad = c(2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), tax = c(348, 224, 224, 277, 277, 277),ptratio = c(14.7, 14.7, 14.7, 18.6, 18.6, 18.6), b = c(395.38, 392.78, 390.55, 396.9, 394.87, 389.43), lstat = c(3.11, 3.81, 2.88, 10.87, 10.97, 18.06), medv = c(42.3, 48.5, 50, 22.6, 24.4, 22.5)), .Names = c("crim", "zn", "indus", "chas", "nox", "rm", "age", "dis", "rad", "tax", "ptratio", "b", "lstat", "medv"), row.names = c("203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried `mapply(function(x, y) predict(x, y, se.fit = TRUE), lmfit, testlist[["predictorNames"]])`? Does `testlist` need to be a list? `mapply` can work on dataframe columns as well, so you could still use `testdf[, predictorNames]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I didn't know, that mapply can work with df columns. Unfortunatley in my case, when I use the df I get the error message: "Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'", and when I use the list I get "Error in testlist[, predictorNames] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: Is `predictorNames` a string vector of variable names? Please show `dput(head(testdf))`, so we know what your data looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know my question is not very precise. Yes it is a string vector: ` predictorNames
[[1]]
 [1] "crim"    "zn"      "indus"   "chas"    "nox"     "rm"      "age"     "dis"     "rad"    
[10] "tax"     "ptratio" "b"       "lstat"   "medv"`

Comment: > dput(head(testdf))
structure(list(crim = c(0.02177, 0.0351, 0.02009, 0.13642, 0.22969, 
0.25199), zn = c(82.5, 95, 95, 0, 0, 0), indus = c(2.03, 2.68, 
2.68, 10.59, 10.59, 10.59), chas = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), nox = c(0.415, 
0.4161, 0.4161, 0.489, 0.489, 0.489), rm = c(7.61, 7.853, 8.034, 
5.891, 6.326, 5.783), age = c(15.7, 33.2, 31.9, 22.3, 52.5, 72.7
), dis = c(6.27, 5.118, 5.118, 3.9454, 4.3549, 4.3549), rad = c(2, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4), tax = c(348, 224, 224, 277, 277, 277),

Comment: ptratio = c(14.7, 
14.7, 14.7, 18.6, 18.6, 18.6), b = c(395.38, 392.78, 390.55, 
396.9, 394.87, 389.43), lstat = c(3.11, 3.81, 2.88, 10.87, 10.97, 
18.06), medv = c(42.3, 48.5, 50, 22.6, 24.4, 22.5)), .Names = c("crim", 
"zn", "indus", "chas", "nox", "rm", "age", "dis", "rad", "tax", 
"ptratio", "b", "lstat", "medv"), row.names = c("203", "204", 
"205", "206", "207", "208"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: HI N.Kunz, welcome to SO. When adding additional information to your post, it is better to edit your post (link is under the tags) directly, than to add info via comments. I've updated the post, so no worries this time, but just a FYI. Also since SO is Markdown friendly you can use backticks '`' to make inline code chunks for things like variable names. Cheers

Comment: Will do in the future, thanks.

Comment: It seems as if all variables from `testdf` are declared in `predictorNames`. Why do you even need the vector then? Just call `testdf`. Please explain what exactly you want to loop. Do you only want to loop over your 3 models, with all variables of `predictorNames` used for `predict`? If so, do `lapply(lmfit, function(x) predict(x, testdf, se.fit = TRUE)`. If that's not it, edit your question and explain clearly what you want your loop to do.